# easy way to extract uppercase in string in R

Tags: r, regex, string, dna-sequence

I am beginner programmer in R.

I have "cCt/cGt" and I want to extract C and G and write it like C>G.

```
test ="cCt/cGt"
str_extract(test, "[A-Z]+$")
```

Comment: So, you have a `cCt/cGt` string, what do you need as output? A `cGt/cGt` string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to look for a mutation in two concatenated strings,  this function should solve your problem:

```
extract_mutation <- function(text){
  splitted <- strsplit(text, split = "/")[[1]] 
  pos <- regexpr("[[:upper:]]", splitted)
  uppercases <- regmatches(splitted, pos)
  mutation <- paste0(uppercases, collapse = ">") 
  return(mutation)
}
```

If the two base exchanges are always at the same index, you could also return the position if you're interested:

```
position <- pos[1]
return(list(mutation, position))
```

instead of the `return(mutation)`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
gsub(".*([A-Z]).*([A-Z]).*", "\\1>\\2", test )
[1] "C>G"
```

Here, we capture the two occurrences of the upper case letters in capturing groups given in parentheses `(...)`. This enables us to **refer** to them (and only to them but not the rest of the string!) in `gsub`'s replacement clause using backreferences `\\1` and `\\2`. In the replacement clause we also include the desired `>`.

Answer (score 0):

You might also capture the 2 uppercase chars followed and preceded by optional lowercase characters and a `/` in between.

```
test ="cCt/cGt"
res = str_match(test, "([A-Z])[a-z]*/[a-z]*([A-Z])")
sprintf("%s>%s", res[2], res[3])
```

Output

```
[1] "C>G"
```

See an [R demo](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyczqSixqFKjuKQoMy@9SJOLqyS1uETBVinZuUQ/2b1EiasotVjBVgEoH5@bWJKcoQGS11FQ0oh21I2K1YxO1K2K1dKHUFAxJU2u4gKgcSVpGkqqxXaqxUo6CkBToo1iIbRxrOb//wA).

---

An exact match for the whole string could be:

```
^[a-z]([A-Z])[a-z]/[a-z]([A-Z])[a-z]$
```